# PHP - Capitalise first character of each word expect certain words

Tags: php, string, lowercase, capitalize

I have a batch of strings like so:

```
tHe iPad hAS gONE ouT of STOCK
PoWER uP YOur iPhone
wHAT moDEL is YOUR aPPLE iPHOne
```

I want to capitalise the first character of each word and have the remaining characters lowercase - except any references of `iPhone` or `iPad`. As in:

By using:

```
ucwords(strtolower($string));
```

This can do most of what is needed but obviously also does it on `iPad`and `iPhone`:

```
The Ipad Has Gone Out Of Stock
Power Up Your Iphone
What Model Is Your Apple Iphone
```

How can I do achieve the below:

```
The iPad Has Gone Out Of Stock
Power Up Your iPhone
What Model Is Your Apple iPhone
```

Comment: Then, you have to check condition for few words. If those words not found, then apply condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ucwords function with exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996446/ucwords-function-with-exceptions)

Comment: Could do a regex; https://regex101.com/r/bH2yY6/1

Comment: `echo preg_replace('@Ip@','iP', ucwords( strtolower( $string ) ) );`?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32564539/2943403

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for this. If you use arrays for the first two arguments, you can define a set of words and replacements:

```
echo str_replace(['Ipad', 'Iphone'], ['iPad', 'iPhone'], ucwords(strtolower($string)));
```

From the documentation:

> If search and replace are arrays, then str_replace() takes a value from each array and uses them to search and replace on subject.

Answer (score 2):

As you know the specific words, and they are limited, why don't you just revert them back after the total capitalization, just as following

```
$string = ucwords(strtolower($string));
$string = str_replace("Ipad","iPad", $string);
$string = str_replace ("Iphone","iPhone", $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having to write the lower- and uppercase version of each word you want to exclude respectively and thus having to write them twice, you could only define them once in an array and using `str_ireplace` instead of `str_replace` like this:

```php
$string = "tHe IPHONE and iPad hAS gONE ouT of STOCK";

$excludedWords = array(
    "iPad",
    "iPhone"
);

echo str_ireplace($excludedWords, $excludedWords, ucwords(strtolower($string)));
```

Which would result in

```
The iPhone And iPad Has Gone Out Of Stock
```

This would then replace all occurrences of these words with the version you've defined in the array.

Edit:

**Keep in mind** that using this, words like "shipadvertise" would be replaced with "shiPadvertise".
If you want to prevent this, you could use a more advanced solution using regular expressions:

```php
$string = "tHe IPHONE and shipadvertise iPad hAS gONE ouT of STOCK";

$excludedWords = array(
    "iPad",
    "iPhone"
);
$excludedWordsReg = array_map(function($a) { return '/(?<=[\s\t\r\n\f\v])'.preg_quote($a).'/i'; }, $excludedWords);

echo preg_replace($excludedWordsReg, $excludedWords, ucwords(strtolower($string)));
```

This would then correctly resolve into

```
The iPhone And Shipadvertise iPad Has Gone Out Of Stock
```

I've used the delimiters for determining words [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/de/function.ucwords.php) uses by default.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to call `strtolower()` on the input string straight away (syck's answer doesn't do this).

I'll offer a pure regex solution that will appropriately target your `ipad` and `iphone` words and capitalize their seconds letter while capitalizing the first letter of all other words.

Code: ([PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/NODUv)) ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xb23ze/1))

```
$strings = [
    "tHe iPad hAS gONE ouT of STOCK
PoWER uP YOur iPhone
wHAT moDEL is YOUR aPPLE iPHOne",           // OP's input string
    "fly the chopper to the helipad.
an audiphone is a type of hearing aid
consisting of a diaphragm that, when
placed against the upper teeth, conveys
sound vibrations to the inner ear"          // some gotcha strings in this element
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo preg_replace_callback('~\bi\K(?:pad|phone)\b|[a-z]+~', function($m) {return ucfirst($m[0]);}, strtolower($string));
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
The iPad Has Gone Out Of Stock
Power Up Your iPhone
What Model Is Your Apple iPhone
---
Fly The Chopper To The Helipad.
An Audiphone Is A Type Of Hearing Aid
Consisting Of A Diaphragm That, When
Placed Against The Upper Teeth, Conveys
Sound Vibrations To The Inner Ear
---
```

Probably the only parts to mention about the regex pattern is that `\K` means "restart the fullstring match" or in other words "consume and forget the previous character(s) in the current match".

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution:

```
<?php

$text = <<<END_TEXT
PoWER uP YOur iPhone
tHe iPad hAS gONE ouT of STOCK 
wHAT moDEL is YOUR aPPLE iPHOne
END_TEXT;

$text = preg_replace(array('/iphone/i', '/iPad/i'), array('iPhone', 'iPad'), $text);
$text = preg_replace_callback('/(\b(?!iPad|iPhone)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', 
     function ($match) { return ucfirst(strtolower($match[1])); }, $text);

echo $text;
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/486319)

Uses a negative lookahead in the regex to exclude the listed words from matching and manipulates the others via a callback to an anonymous function. That way, you can do any kind of manipulation, for example reversing the string.

Answer (score 0):

This will might help you.. i write this code for my use and its working perfectly for me...

```
<?php
function strtocap($arg){
    $finalStr = array();

    $argX = explode(" ",$arg);
    if(is_array($argX)){
        foreach($argX as $v){
            $finalStr[] = ucfirst(strtolower($v));
        }
    }
return implode(" ",$finalStr);
}

$str = "Your unForMated StrInG";
echo strtocap($str);
?>
```