# PHP Ucwords with or and special characters

Tags: php, lowercase

Here is what I'm doing.

I have a couple of strings that is uppercase

> †HELLO THERE 
>   DAY OR NIGHT

So to convert them, I'm using the following code:

```
ucwords(strtolower($string));
```

Here is the end result:

> †hello There
>   Day Or Night

How can I ignore the `†` or any special characters so it the words can show

> †Hello There

and how can I keep words like or all lowercase.

Comment: What do you mean by "special characters"? Is "é" a special character?

Comment: Well, I'm talking about any special character like this † (in this case).

Comment: So how should `†HELLO†THERE†HOW†ARE†YOU` be outputted?

Comment: most likely as `†Hello†There†How†Are†You`

Comment: @KevinDavis Any luck with this?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735798/title-case-a-string-containing-one-or-more-last-names-while-handling-names-with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
print preg_replace_callback('#([a-zA-ZÄÜÖäüö0-9]+)#',function($a){
   return ucfirst(strtolower($a[0]));
 },
 '†hello THERE'
);
```

`[a-zA-ZÄÜÖäüö0-9]+` find a word that only has this chars

You can also use this instead `[\w]+` 
 see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

`preg_replace_callback` call a function on the found result

`function($a){}` do something with the result, here `ucfirst(strtolower())`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $lowerString = strtolower($string);
    $stringArray = explode($lowerString, ' ');
    foreach ($stringArray as $key => $singleString) {
        $i = 0; 
        $formatedString = '';
        $upcased = false;
        for ($i; $i < strlen($singleString); $i++) {
            $ascNum = chr($singleString[$i]);
            $word = $singleString[$i];
            if (!$upcased) {
              if (($ascNum >= 65 && $ascNum <= 90) || ($ascNum >= 97 && $ascNum <= 122) ) {
                $word = ucwords($word);
                $upcased = true;
              }
            }
            $formatedString .= $word;  
        }
        $stringArray[$key] = $formatedString;
    }
    $result = implode(' ',$stringArray);
```

maybe a little complicated, but a clean idea.

Answer (score 0):

`ucwords(strtolower("†HELLO THERE"),"† ");` the second parameter of ucwords is an [optional delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php). So by including both dagger and space, ucwords will work for the examples provided.

for your second question, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996446/ucwords-function-with-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming words are separated by a space:

```
<?php
function custom_ucfirst($s)
{
    $s = strtolower($s);

    $e = (strpos($s, ' ') !== false ? explode(' ', $s) : array($s));

    $keep_all_lowercase = array('or','and','but');

    foreach($e as $k=>$v)
    {
        if(!in_array($v, $keep_all_lowercase))
        {
            $str_split = str_split($v);

            foreach($str_split as $k2=>$v2)
            {
                if(in_array($v2, range('a','z')))
                {
                    $str_split[$k2] = strtoupper($v2);
                    break;
                }
            }

            $e[$k] = implode('', $str_split);
        }
    }

    return implode(' ', $e);
}

echo custom_ucfirst('†HELLO THERE .cloud. or sky what a nice an*d ()good day.');

// †Hello There .Cloud. or Sky What A Nice An*d ()Good Day.
```