# Make Sure Certain Words are Lower Case

Tags: php, html

I'm just messing around with PHP again and I need some help.

I'm working on a project where I type a Magic: The Gathering card in and it goes to the URL for that card and saves the picture to my Pictures folder.

I use `ucwords` to capitalize the words when I save them to a file.  However, I want to make sure certain words are lower case (the, and, of, etc.).  How can I do that?

Thanks.

Here's my `results.php` code:

```
<?php

$results = $_POST['cardname'];
$query_array = array('name'=>$_POST['cardname'], 'type'=> 'card', '.jpg');
$url = "http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?".http_build_query($query_array);
$img = "Pictures/" . ucwords($results) . ".png";
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
?>

<img src="<?php echo $url ?>">
<br><br><br><br>
<form action="cardfetch.php">
  <input type="submit" value="Back">
</form>
```

Comment: `<form action="cardfetch.php">` for one thing defaults to a GET method yet you're using a POST array. However the POST `cardname` is unknown here, so for me the question's unclear and if you're using another form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996446/ucwords-function-with-exceptions

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's just a crappy form for clicking to get back to cardfetch.php... this is the results page.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure. Did you look at the link that was left in comments?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, I did, thanks!

Comment: You're most welcome.